# Como passar argumentos no console do Eclipse Ide?

Tags: java, eclipse

Como passar argumentos no console do Eclipse? Por exemplo esse programa:

```
public class Eco { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i=0; i<args.length; i++) 
            System.out.println(args[i] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Consegui executar normalmente no cmd passando um argumento e ele exibe, e no Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Clique com botão direito no projeto.
2. Vá até **Debug As > Debug Configurations** or **Run As > Run Configurations**.
3. Clique na aba **Arguments**.
4. Entre no seu programa **Program Arguments**
5. Clique **Apply** ou **Debug**

[image]

Resposta original: [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574543/how-to-pass-console-arguments-to-application-in-eclipse)